# Which olympic sports would let aliens fit in by eliminating size, strength etc. advantages?

Tags: aliens, xenobiology, sports

TLDR: Looking for Olympic sports where doubling, or halfing, someone's strength, size or toughness won't materially help or hurt them in that sport.  They do exist.

The alien spaceships spectacularly land on Earth.  Everyone wonders what they are about until they say directly: they want to qualify their "countries" for the Olympics.   "Oh. That's *it?*" Yeah, pretty much.

Just one problem.  Their strength, size or toughness are unlike humans - and they have wildly imbalanced some games - crying for separation as exist for men and women.

- The Cheetari *dominate* **snowboarding** and **sprint skating**
- The Shorstackians can't even climb aboard their **bobsleigh** and
- **Hockey** has put nine of the Big Eyed Aliens in the hospital.

But having a separate competition solely for Cheetari defeats the purpose of the Olympics.

**Not all sports have an imbalance problem.**  There's an apparently obscure sport called **[curling](https://youtu.be/ZucaARSNZhQ?t=5m52s)** which requires strategy and refinement of fine motion rather than raw power. Sure enough, the slow moving Cephalapori fit in very well, able and fast enough (on ice) to deliver stones and sweep - *only one broom though*.  They're media darlings, rocking their Detroit Redwings caps and calling "yeongmi" (no one has told them you just say "broom"), and **winning about half** of games, except against the Nordic nations or Korea. The Cheetara jumped on it too once they realized nobody would complain about them.  The game puts all races at par.  So there is an example of a sport that works.

Summer Olympics are in two years.

**Which other Olympic sports have mechanics which inherently tend to annul advantages or disadvantages in strength, height, size, or toughness?**

For this question, "no such game exists" is an acceptable answer *if supported*.

Comment: @Harper, any game which excludes skills (strength, speed, whatever) has to be based on only chance. As far as I know poker or dice rolling has never been an Olympic sport.

Comment: @Harper you should look at things like shooting for the summer and curling for the winter as these are based more on technique.

Comment: They could compete in sports that combine different sports, like triathlon and the others. While one species would have a definite advantage in one part, another would have the advantage in the next, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The sports that are based more on style:

Winter Olympics: Figure Skating, Ice Dancing

Summer Olympics: Gymnastics, Synchronized Swimming, Diving

plus Equestrian because you are using your skill to control another creature that has the speed/strength/etc. Of course, the aliens who are able to control a horse telepathically have a big advantage there.

Comment: Only based EXCLUSIVELY on style. If a group of figure skaters can land quintuple jumps with ease, they are going to be way ahead in competition.

Comment: I don’t think the aliens who weigh 400kg are going to do very well in the equestrian events, except possibly as mounts.

Comment: @MikeScott But the average weight in Equestrian 2012 was 67.2kg. So plenty of humans can't do that either (aside from skill requirements).

Answer (score 2):

Chess

These aliens figured space travel, so the game should be easy for them to understand and even if they don't have any hands I'm sure they would be able to rig something.

Comment: Chess isn't an olympic sport

Comment: sorry to disappoint you, chess is highly based on skills.

Comment: All sports are based on skills, but Chess at least seems to be a skill those aliens can learn and compete against humans without being impaired by their physiology. 

Chess was proposed as a sport for the next olympics.